# How to make an if statement with conditions that include "and" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a password and confirmation password match, without them both being just left blank.

I would like to add in this part about the password fields not being able to be left blank, in the if statement, by saying the passwords have the same value, and these values are not blank.

The function worked fine when it was just the if statement, saying that the passwords had to match in order for the welcome alert to come up, and have found that the and symbol in javascript is && but i don't know how to use it in the context.

```
var check = function() {

if (document.getElementById('psw').value ==
document.getElementById('psw-repeat').value)
&&
(document.getElementById('psw').value) != "" 
&&
(document.getElementById('psw-repeat').value) != "" } 

else {
alert("passwords do not match")
  }
}
```

I would expect this code to say that the passwords haven't been filled out, if they haven't, to say welcome if the password and confirmation password match, and to say the passwords do not match if they do not match.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong but would love if anyone could help.

:))

Comment: Everything has to go in a  single outer pair of parentheses `if ( ... everything ... )`

Comment: If you formatted your code better you would see your problem. I would get a linter in your IDE, because it would have pointed you to the issue.

Comment: Please, review the parentheses and the code, they `if` sentence is closed on the first comparison: `document.getElementById('psw').value ==
document.getElementById('psw-repeat').value`.

Comment: Examples widely available online: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: Along with the answers provided I'd suggest utilizing things like the [required](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) attribute as well for situations like this to let the browser help guide users also.

Comment: thank you all, i do need to get better at setting code out clearly. the help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not closing the whole if statement with ()

Answer (score 0):

Okay, best way to do conditions it like following.
why best

- optimized, you don't need to get values from dom again and again for
  condition checking
- easy to read if condition.
- If code is not readable then not the best code

So always try to break the conditions

```
function() {      
        var password = document.getElementById('psw').value;
        var password_repeat = document.getElementById('psw-repeat').value;
        if (password == password_repeat && password != ""  && password_repeat != "")
        { 
                // code ..........
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert("passwords do not match")
        }
    }
```

For better code checking and styling, use some IDEs like VSCode Atom Bracket 
but personally I like the VSCode

Comment: thank you very much, im using atom but im just not the best at setting it out clearly :))

Answer (score 0):

The only real problem is out-of-place parentheses and curly braces, but this way adds a couple of improvements beyond those simple fixes.

```js
// Select HTML elements
const psw = document.getElementById("psw");
const pswRepeat = document.getElementById("psw-repeat");
const checkBtn = document.getElementById("checkBtn");

// Listen for button clicks
checkBtn.addEventListener("click", check);

// Validate passwords
function check(){
  if(pswRepeat.value === psw.value && psw.value != ""){
    // We know they are the same, and psw is not empty (so neither is pswRepeat)
    alert("good");
  }
  else{
    alert("passwords do not match");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="psw" />
<input id="psw-repeat" />
<button id="checkBtn">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the parenthesis. 
You need better indentation to detect these kinds of problems early and some separation of logic to keep the code readable.
Something like this :

```js
var check = function() {

  if (isValid()) {
    //Welcome here
  } else {
    alert("passwords do not match")
  }
}

function isValid() {
  var psw = document.getElementById('psw').value;
  var repeatPsw = document.getElementById('psw-repeat').value;

  //Logic to check for password
  if (psw == repeatPsw &&
    psw != "" &&
    repeatPsw != ""
  )
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

Comment: yeah i really need to get better at setting code out, thank you very much for helping :)